# Javascript in-page scrolling offset

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, anchor

This is more of a problem solving question. I'm trying to leverage the native in-page scrolling that browsers give to allow mobile users to skip to the content which they need more easily.

The issue is that I have a sticky header on the page, so using the native `<a id="section1"></a>`, visiting `#section1` means that the scroll position is behind the sticky header.

Is there a way, using plain-old JS (or even CSS if possible!), to offset the scroll position by an amount of pixels? Or is there a more elegant JS solution for this which would work in IE11, Edge, Chrome & FF?

```
<header> ... </header> <!-- site-wide sticky header using position: sticky -->
<main>
  <nav> <!-- page-specific sticky nav using position: sticky (placed under <header />) -->
    <a href="#top">Top</a>
    <a href="#bottom">Bottom</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <section>
      <a id="top"></a>
      ...
      ...
      ...
    </section>
    ...
    <section>
      <a id="bottom"></a>
      ...
      ...
      ...
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the heights of the headers then you can change the `top` of the anchor like the below:

```css
header {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0; /* required */
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 40px; /* required */
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

section > a {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
}

section > div {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

#topDiv {
  background: blue;
}

#bottomDiv {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<header> ... </header> <!-- site-wide sticky header using position: sticky -->
<main>
  <nav> <!-- page-specific sticky nav using position: sticky (placed under <header />) -->
    <a href="#top">Top</a>
    <a href="#bottom">Bottom</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <section>
      <a id="top"></a>
      <div id="topDiv" style="height: 500px; width: 100%" >
        Content
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <a id="bottom"></a>
      <div id="bottomDiv" style="height: 500px; width: 100%" >
        Content
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```